# Can I post items on the eBay store using their API

Tags: ebay-api

I'm curious,
Using eBay's API can I post items to the eBay store on behalf of users?
As in, can I build my system through which i can post items to the eBay store?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you want to just post items and leave them it's relatively simple.  You can also manage the inventory / orders / shipments etc which is a lot more advanced.

Here's a useful guide in the eBay API section:

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/howto/XML_ListingAndSelling/ListingAndSelling_listing.html